# Inherit feature color from another feature automatically with ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, attribute-table, color, relationship-class

I'm working on a **"Ftth"** project and there are many repetitive tasks. So, I have to connect the house to the closure through a wire. Whenever I give a color to each closure, the link and the house should take the same color automatically.

If this is achievable using relation class, (using ArcCatalog) how can I do it to save a lot of effort and time?

[image]

Comment: What GIS software are you using to try to do this?  What have tried with that software?

Comment: The closure would have some sort of code saying its red/blue, you just need to set symbology of your house to that code, so you need to add the closure code to the house as part of your edit.